# Using excel formula that does not overkill the file to automate process

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-automation

I have an Excel dataset and I can't use any plug-ins - only Excel formulas, for the following task:
There is a table: Column A, containing text labels, and Column B, containing numbers corresponding to each label (not in an ascending order).
The task is: when making a new unique entry in Column A, there should be a way to find out which numbers are already taken and/or which numbers are available to be used in Column B.
Please advise as to which formula to use, whether a different sheet containing all the available numbers should be made etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we already have data in cols **A** & **B** like:

[image]

Each unique item has its own number.  We are going to make an entry in **A21**. The following formula will assign an old number if the item appears above and it will assign a new, unused, number if the item does not appear above:

In **B21** enter:

```
=IF(A21="","",IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A21,A21)=1,1+MAX($B$1:B20),INDEX($B$1:B20,MATCH(A21,$A$1:A20,0))))
```

Naturally, you would adjust the formula to the point you want to make new entries.

Comment: thanks for the reply :) Another question: what if there's a specific numbering format for the lists (eg. KL09400, KL09401 etc.) and it also happens that there are available numbers in-between some already taken ones (eg. 4 and 7 are taken, therefore you could choose between 5 and 6 for the new entry)? Basically, I am looking for a way to get the unused numbers given a list of all possible values, if that makes any sense. Is that possible in any way?

Comment: @Andrea  That would require a macro rather than a simple formula.